# Does Flesh Ward prevent Stamina loss from one source multiple times?

Tags: arkham-horror

The Flesh Ward spell says

> **Any Phase**: Cast and exhaust to ignore all Stamina loss being dealt to you from one source. Discard this spell if the Ancient One awakens.

Is a 'source' considered a physical entity or more so considered an action or event from some entity, i.e. can I use this to prevent stamina loss from a specific monster through several attacks received, eventually evade it (if say I simply had no capacity to have enough successes to kill it), then next turn still avoid stamina loss from it?

Comment: Why the note about "this combat"? Flesh Ward doesn't use that wording.

Comment: Good catch. My mind was thinking to put that in a different question I posted recently, but I accidentally put it here. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 7 of the [Arkham Horror FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/FAQs/Complete_Arkham_FAQ.pdf)

says

> Q: When exactly can Flesh Ward be cast?
>
> A: When you are told to lose 1 or more points of Stamina,
> you may cast Flesh Ward to prevent that loss. For instance, this can work on the Stamina from a single failed Combat check. This does not make the investigator immune to fur- ther harm from that source, it only prevents it one time.

The answer appears to be that 'one source' implies one singular event, like a single attack from a monster.

Comment: Yes, and this should be clear from the spell's text. It says "being dealt to you". It can only prevent what's currently being dealt to you, not something that's going to be dealt later.

Comment: I don't feel like I have the right sense yet for interpreting these all the time. I could have easily confused this to mean loss being dealt to me for the duration of the game. Sometimes reading too literally gets me in trouble too.

Comment: P8 from the FAQ also address this directly: "Q: Can Flesh Ward protect an investigator from all damage caused by a given monster during a whole combat? A: No. (In combat, the “one source” of damage Flesh Ward allows an investigator to ignore is the Stamina loss from a single failed Combat check, not all damage caused by a particular monster for the duration of the combat.)" and backs up your answer.  I did not feel this warrented an answer of my own so hope this addon helps=)